# How to Hide nested HTTP Samples(Child samples) in the Jmeter HTML Report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have generated the Jmeter HTML Report but in the Graphs Child samples data is displayed (But I checked Generate parent sample Check box in Transaction controller).Where do I need to change if I want only Transactions to be displayed in graphs
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F5Aw.png)

I have used below command to run from Command line but Some graphs are empty and Request Summary is also empty but Child samples data is not displayed in the graphs

jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false -n -t E:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\jp\BookWithTemplate.jmx -l E:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\CSV\BWT.csv  -e -o E:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\GeneratedReports

In reports I need to have the results only for Transactions not for Child samples.
In all the graphs Child samples should not be displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected result. Either you change the naming convention. Instead of Home-1, home-2..use only Home and provide data as input from csv. So, it will come under Home..and so on. Or one you data is generated in the csv...change the labels in the csv to consolidate in one group. Example replace all homepage-1, homepage-2 to Homepage and generate the graph later using [HTML Report Tool.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_gui)
[image]

Hope this helps.

Update;- Only transaction without any child sample. You can use export trasaction summary to filter the output. Check [Filtering configuaration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements) and steps provide in [here](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/reporting-feature-in-jmeter/)

Comment: This worked but in graphs Child sample results are combined with the Transaction results.I need only transactions data in the graphs.Thanks

Comment: Remove the child sample data from the csv then and generate the report.

Comment: If I remove child samples data in csv, Request Summary pie chart is displayed empty

Comment: Filtering Configuration Helped

Comment: Glad to hear that:)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want child samples to appear in your HTML report:

In the listener page(where you have saved the result file as **E:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\CSV\BWT.csv** and which is the source file of HTML report) -> click on configure button -> uncheck the Save Sub Result option -> Hit Done button

Now do the execution and try to genertae HTML reports. It will not contain child samples(Sub Requests)

[image]

Reference :

[Configure result file to customize HTML report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCBPpKcLhiA&feature=youtu.be&list=PLkkGqdBS1r094KcNXRy4Q-v5biuNWv-h7&t=942)

[How to generate HTML report in JMeter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7Ou6ju6x9c&list=PLkkGqdBS1r094KcNXRy4Q-v5biuNWv-h7&index=6)